# Implementing an economic model in Python's GEKKO

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, modeling, gekko, economics

I have a model

[image: model]

where I should find u, that maximizes total consumption usefulness.
`u = ln(c(t))`, where `c(t)` is consumption.

`dk/dt` shows the dynamics of investments (production - consumption) we own when the `u` is optimized

I have a problem with implementing this model in Python's GEKKO

Here is code I've tried to write, it doesn't work. I don`t know where is my problem

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
# time points
n=501
m.time = np.linspace(0,90,n)

# constants
koef = 0.1 # коефієнти 

# керування
lb_cal = np.log(100)
ub_cal = np.log(k)
k = m.Var(value=1000) # інвестиції
u = m.MV(value=101,lb=lb_cal,ub=ub_cal)
u.STATUS = 1
u.DCOST = 0

# investments rate
m.Equation(k.dt() == 10*k**(2/3)-koef*k-u)

J = m.Var(value=6.8) # objective (profit)
Jf = m.FV() # final objective
Jf.STATUS = 1

m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
m.Equation(J.dt() == np.exp(-m.time)*u)

m.Maximize(Jf) # maximize profit

m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
m.solve(disp=False) # Solve

print('Мах загальної корисності: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
plt.figure(1) # plot results
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,J.value,'r--',label='general utility')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'b-',label='investments')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,u.value,'k--',label='rate')
plt.xlabel('Time (yr)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Would be extra grateful if someone could explain where is my problem

Comment: Thank you for editing my question! Now it looks much better and understandable

Answer (score 0):

Reformulating the problem gives a successful solution without the upper bound for `c(t)`. Use the `gekko` function `m.log()` instead of `np.log()`. The `m.integral()` function simplifies the problem. Additional details are available in the [gekko documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html).

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
# time points
n=101
m.time = np.linspace(0,90,n)
delta = 1
t = m.Param(m.time)

# constants
koef = 0.1 # коефієнти 

# керування
k = m.Var(value=1000) # інвестиції
c = m.MV(lb=100)
c.STATUS = 1; c.DCOST = 0

# investments rate
m.Equation(k.dt() == k - 0.1*k - c)

# maximize last value at T=90
p = np.zeros(n); p[-1] = 1
final = m.Param(p)
J = m.Intermediate(m.integral(m.exp(-delta*t)*m.log(c)))
m.Maximize(final * J) # maximize final profit

m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000
m.solve(disp=True) # Solve

try:
    # add inequality constraint
    m.Equation(c <= 10*k**(2/3) - 0.1*k)

    # solve again with inequality constraint
    m.solve(disp=True) # Solve
except:
    print('no feasible solution with inequality constraint')

print('Мах загальної корисності: ' + str(J.value[-1]))
plt.figure(1) # plot results
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,J.value,'r--',label='general utility')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'b-',label='consumption')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,c.value,'k--',label='rate')
plt.xlabel('Time (yr)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

When adding the upper bound for `c(t)` as `m.Equation(c <= 10*k**(2/3) - 0.1*k)`, there is no feasible solution. Try adding a less restrictive constraint and tighten the constraint until the problem becomes infeasible. This helps to identify problems with enforcing the constraint.

One other issue to check is that `m.exp(-delta*t)` quickly becomes zero so the only contributions to the integral occur in the first few years. The value of `delta` may need to be updated to a lower value (maybe `0.01`) to reflect the true depreciation rate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I've simplified my model, so now it works in code and economic connotation as well:
how it was `f(k(t))`=`10*k**(2/3)`
how it looks now: `f(k(t))`=`k**(1)`
Economically it means that Capital and Labor affect the production function in the exact correlation (so no power coefficients is needed)

About `delta` - yes, it should be lower. With `delta`=`0.01` it works good